# Change app/etc/local.xml programmatically (simplexml?)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, simplexml

does anybody know the best way to change a node in local.xml within a custom module? Is there functionality within magento I can use or do I need to focus on a simplexml function in php?

Currenly I am trying for example this, but does't do anything

```
    // load the document
// the root node is <info/> so we load it into $info
$info = simplexml_load_file('/app/etc/local.xml');

// update
$info->config->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host = 'test';

// save the updated document
$info->asXML('/app/etc/local.xml');
```

Comment: Do you want to change it **temporarily** or **permanently**?

Comment: permanently. For example to change the host or dbname